# Restforce Salesforce REST API INVALID_SESSION_ID: Session expired or invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, salesforce, restforce

I am using the Rails [Restforce gem](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce) to connect to my app to Salesforce.

I am able to authenticate without issue and make calls to add/delete records.  However after some period of time (many hours), I begin to get:

`Restforce::UnauthorizedError: INVALID_SESSION_ID: Session expired or invalid`

From my understanding the Restforce gem should handle getting a new token automatically.  Here is how I am connecting:

```
@client = Restforce.new oauth_token: options[:salesforce_token],
      refresh_token: options[:salesforce_refresh_token],
      instance_url:  options[:salesforce_instance_url],
      client_id:     sales_force_client_id,
      client_secret: sales_force_client_secret,
      authentication_callback: Proc.new { |x| Rails.logger.debug x.to_s }
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Update: here are the app permission settings.  To confirm I am able to do what I need via the API, but the session expires after a day or so.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure `options[:salesforce_refresh_token]` is populated?

Comment: @trueinViso yes it is populated.

Comment: I'm assuming you set something up like [this](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/1fbeb1c469ed581def8a59216f258a030c0b50bf/68747470733a2f2f662e636c6f75642e6769746875622e636f6d2f6173736574732f3337383133352f3935343737322f64373132383435342d303431642d313165332d386633352d3465613637323438323663612e706e67) in your account to get the refresh tokens working?

Comment: @trueinViso yes - I have updated my question with a pic of the settings.